# Breaking a safe

Tags: string, algorithm

Hi I  got the following question:

> We have a safe with 4 digits (each digit is between 0-9) password. The safe will be open if you give to it a string that contains a sub string with the correct 4 digit password. 
>   For example: safe with the code 2345 will be open if you give for example the string '123456'. the safe will be open in this case after the digit 5. 
>   you need to give the **shortest** string that necessarily will open the safe.

I tried many ways but couldn't find a better way than the naive string that contains: `0000000100020003...`

Comment: De Bruin sequence. GIYF

Comment: and a link ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Comment: Ok. I misspelled the name. Forgive me, for I am Dutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is using the [De Bruin sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). In Python (from wikipedia):

```
def de_bruijn(k, n):
    """
    De Bruijn sequence for alphabet k
    and subsequences of length n.
    """
    try:
        # let's see if k can be cast to an integer;
        # if so, make our alphabet a list
        _ = int(k)
        alphabet = list(map(str, range(k)))

    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        alphabet = k
        k = len(k)

    a = [0] * k * n
    sequence = []

    def db(t, p):
        if t > n:
            if n % p == 0:
                sequence.extend(a[1:p + 1])
        else:
            a[t] = a[t - p]
            db(t + 1, p)
            for j in range(a[t - p] + 1, k):
                a[t] = j
                db(t + 1, t)
    db(1, 1)
    return "".join(alphabet[i] for i in sequence)
```

And in your case it is:

```
print(de_bruijn("0123456789", 4))
```

Outputs a huge number which I won't copy-paste here.